# Is there any way or method to figure out my mistake to get solution for this command?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, read-host

I type this Powershell command

```
PS C:\Users\User>  new-aduser -name "Tracy Jones" -givenname "Tracy" -surname "Jones" -samaccountname "tjones" userprincipalname "tjones@adatum.com" -path "ou=marketing,dc=abc,dc=com" -accountpassword(-Read-Host -assecurestring "type password for user") -enables $true
```

It shows me this kind of error message:

> -Read-Host : The term '-Read-Host' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
> program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
>
> At line:1 char:184
>
> - ... path "ou=marketing,dc=abc,dc=com" -accountpassword(-Read-Host -assecu ...
> - ```
>                                                      ~~~~~~~~~~
>   ```
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (-Read-Host:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: You probably want to add a space after account password and remove the dash infront of Read-Host. But I'm not sure, if calling Read-Host this way is even supported. Maybe you'll have to read the password first and call new-aduser in a second step

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$pass=Read-Host -Prompt "Type password for user" -AsSecureString -Force
$user=@{
Name="Tracy Jones" 
givenname="Tracy" 
surname="Jones"
samaccountname="tjones" 
userprincipalname="tjones@adatum.com"
path="ou=marketing,dc=abc,dc=com"
accountpassword=$pass
enabled=$true
}
new-aduser @user
```

- `Read-Host` in separate variable and statement.
- `Enables` corrected to `Enabled`
- Done splatting for long cmdlet

Comment: Tracy needs an opening quote character for givenname ;)

Comment: Oh @Theo sorry for the mistake while copying, didn't notice it, edits are welcome in this case

Comment: These things happen, especially now I think that SO has changed the Syntax Highlighter and because of that almost all PowerShell code suddenly looks like it's almost all olive-greenish comments. Small mistakes now don't really stand out anymore..

Answer (score 0):

$passvalue = Read-Host -assecurestring "type password for user". Take the password in a variable then use it as the value for -accountpassword parameter.